# R creating a cluster based on overlapping /intersecting rows

Tags: r

I have the following data frame in R that has overlapping data in the two columns a_sno and b_sno

```
a_sno<- c(4,5,5,6,6,7,9,9,10,10,10,11,13,13,13,14,14,15,21,21,21,22,23,23,24,25,183,184,185,185,200)
b_sno<-c(5,4,6,5,7,6,10,13,9,13,14,15,9,10,14,10,13,11,22,23,24,21,21,25,21,23,185,185,183,184,200)
df = data.frame(a_sno, b_sno)
```

If you take a close look at the data you can see that the 4,5,6&7 intersect/ overlap and I need to put them into a group called 1.
Like wise 9,10,13,14 into group 2, 11 and 15 into group 3 etc.... and 200 is not intersecting with any other row but still need to be assigned its own group.

The resulting output should look like this:

```
---------
group|sno
---------
1    | 4
1    | 5
1    | 6
1    | 7
2    | 9
2    | 10
2    | 13
2    | 14
3    | 11
3    | 15
4    | 21
4    | 22
4    | 23
4    | 24
4    | 25
5    | 183
5    | 184
5    | 185
6    | 200
```

Any help to get this done is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: why do you have the new group 3 at 11 in your example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient solution but you could use graphs to do this:

```
#sort the data by row and remove duplicates
df = unique(t(apply(df,1,sort)))

#load the library
library(igraph)

#make a graph with your data
graph <-graph.data.frame(df)

#decompose it into components
components <- decompose.graph(graph)

#get the vertices of the subgraphs
result<-lapply(seq_along(components),function(i){
  vertex<-as.numeric(V(components[[i]])$name)
  cbind(rep(i,length(vertex)),vertex)
  })

#make the final dataframe
output<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,result))
colnames(output)<-c("group","sno")
output
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. It definitely gives me the desired output for the 31 rows as posted in the question. However it is pretty slow as you said. I am dealing a 1.4M rows dataset. Is there a efficient way to further improve the performance?

Comment: Can't think of a completely different solution but you might want to try sorting the data by row and removing duplicates to reduce the number of edges in the graph, I added it in the code. Hopefully an R expert will come up with something faster.

Comment: Thank you again. I could run this on the 1.4M rows. just took a little longer.I will mark this as a solution. But will be definitely seeking ways to improve it.